# mySQL query to carve out subset

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query to carve out a subset from a table.

Table A: {a, b, c, d, e}
Table B: {a, b, c}

I would like to carve out Table B content from Table A. I can do a double loop to accomplish that. First to loop through Table A, then loop through Table B. If the content is in Table B, skip. Otherwise, select.

Are there any special joins to accomplish that instead of doing loop within a loop? Thx

Comment: SQL is a set-based language.  You don't loop your records.

Comment: You don't provide enough information in order for people to help you.  Please read this guide on how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what do you mean by carve out , if you wnat all records tha are nio in be jon both tables where table1.a <> tabel2.a and so so on, but you have to check iof you find all records

Answer (score 0):

Which columns do you want to compare between the 2 tables?  a, b ,c?  Based on your example, below query gives you the logic.

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e
FROM TableA tblA
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM TableB
    WHERE a = tblA.a AND b = tblA.b AND c = tblA.c
)
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I am looking for! Have not touched SQL for the past two decades and forgot what I learned LOL. Much appreciated.